# Search for two product with the same activity

Tags: android, search

I'm adding the voice search functionality to my app.
From all the examples I found I need to add something like this:

```
<application ... >
<activity android:name=".SearchableActivity" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />

    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
               android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
</activity>
...
```

in the `Android Manifest` where `"@xml/searchable"` points to a resource like this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:hint="@string/search_hint">
```

The `search_hint` string is something like `"Search <content-or-product>"`.

The problem is that only one

`<meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable" android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>`

can be specified for an `Activity`. So the question is: how can I use the same `Activity` to handle the searches for two products?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the functionality of SearchableActivity doesn't change for either product, you could get around the manifest limitation by creating two activities which extend SearchableActivity.

```
<activity android:name=".SearchProductActivityA">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
               android:resource="@xml/searchable_a"/>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".SearchProductActivityB" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
               android:resource="@xml/searchable_b"/>
</activity>
```

Comment: right but I was wondering whether there is a better solution. It just seems wrong to create a new Activity only for that. What about if I you many products (like I do)...

Comment: I guess a compromise would be to change the text to something generic like "Search Product". I don't see another way around it if it's only possible to define one Searchable in metadata.